# Class takes no arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, exception, methods

```
class MyClass:
    def say():
        print("hello")

mc = MyClass()
mc.say()
```

I am getting error: `TypeError: say() takes no arguments (1 given)`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I can keep adding duplicates, but you should've found these links in a heartbeat with google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because methods in a class expect the first argument to be `self`. This `self` parameter is passed internally by python as it always sends a reference to itself when calling a method, even if it's unused within the method

```
class MyClass:
    def say(self):
        print("hello")

mc = MyClass()
mc.say()
>> hello
```

Alternatively, you can make the method static and remove the `self` parameter

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def say():
        print("hello")

mc = MyClass()
mc.say()
>> hello
```