# I get a Traceback Type Error Employee() takes no arguments, when trying to create a class method to parse string and create object in python

Tags: python, class, methods, typeerror

I get a Traceback Type Error Employee() takes no arguments, when trying to create a class method to parse string and create object in python

```
  class Employee(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, emp_str):
        first_name, last_name, pay = emp_str.split('-')
        return cls(first_name, last_name, pay)**

    emp_str_1 = 'Larry-David-100000'
    new_emp_1 = Employee.from_string(emp_str_1)
    print(new_emp_1.first_name, new_emp_1.last_name, new_emp_1.pay)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\class_method.py", line 14, in <module>
    new_emp_1 = Employee.from_string(emp_str_1)
  File "C:\class_method.py", line 8, in from_string
    return cls(first_name, last_name, pay)
TypeError: Employee() takes no arguments
```

Comment: You didn't define an `__init__()` method for the class, so it is using the default init which takes no parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Car() takes no arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626731/typeerror-car-takes-no-arguments)

Comment: I thought only instance methods need  __init__ and this is not required for class methods.

Comment: Your `cls(first_name, last_name, pay)` is going to call the class' `__init__`, because it's going to instantiate an object, just like `Employee(first_name, last_name, pay)`. So you still need an `__init__` function that accepts those parameters.

Comment: If your classmethod is *not* instantiating an Employee object, then yes `__init__` is not needed.

Comment: How can I run the @classmethod without instantiating an Employee object? Because I keep getting the TypeError Employee() take no arguments error.

Comment: The problem is not with the classmethod itself; it's because the classmethod calls `cls(first_name, last_name, pay)`.  What do you expect that to even do?  Within your Employee class, where do you expect `first_name`, `last_name`, `pay` to be handled?

Comment: I am trying to implement the @classmethod to first parse the string and then as an alternative constructor to the __init__ method. I read that the classmethod can also be used as an alternative constructor to the regular instance method.

Comment: I don't know what you read but it could be missing some information or examples. A class needs to call `__init__` to instantiate the class. And your use-case here is instantiating the class with `cls(...)`. Where else is it supposed to store `.first_name` and `.last_name` for every Employee object. Using a @classmethod to construct an object is useful for factory design patterns like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/682545/2745495.

Comment: I suggest re-reading the difference between instance and class methods, instance and class variables, and also how classes and instances are constructed and used in Python.